# How to run external program that takes its input with echo from julia

Tags: command-line, julia

I have a very basic problem:

I have a file and I need to run a command for each word inside. Lets assume the word I have now is "example_word" the command I need to run is as follows:

```
readall(run(pipeline(`echo example_word`,`flookup model.foma`))
```

Unfortunatelly I cannot get the output of this command from repl. I search on the net and readstring is recommended for it. When I try it I got the following error:

```
julia> read(pipeline(`echo example_word`,`flookup model.foma`),String)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching read(::Base.OrCmds, ::Type{String})
Closest candidates are:
  read(::AbstractString, ::Any...) at io.jl:109
  read{T}(::IO, ::Type{T}, ::Int64, ::Int64...) at io.jl:235
  read{T}(::IO, ::Type{T}, ::Integer, ::Integer...) at io.jl:236
  ...

julia> readstring(pipeline(`echo example_word`,`flookup model.foma`),String)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching readstring(::Base.OrCmds, ::Type{String})
Closest candidates are:
  readstring(::Base.AbstractCmd) at process.jl:581
  readstring(::Base.AbstractCmd, ::Union{Base.FileRedirect,IO,RawFD}) at process.jl:581
```

Comment: `x = read(pipeline(\`echo example_word\`,\`flookup model.foma\`)),String)` or `x = readstring(pipeline(   ))` depending on version. You may want to `parse(Int,x)` later

Comment: @DanGetz None of them worked. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: note the `readstring` version doesn't have a `String` parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String(read(pipeline(`echo example_word`,`cat`)))
```

or (as @DanGetz suggested)

```
readstring(pipeline(`echo example_word`,`cat`))
```

Just replace `cat` with the command you want to use, I didn't have it on my computer.

I the future you might have realised that you didn't need to give `readstring` the `String` parameter by looking at the error message a bit closer :)

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching readstring(::Base.OrCmds, ::Type{String})
Closest candidates are:
  readstring(::Base.AbstractCmd) at process.jl:581
```

Comment: +1. Worth pointing out that `readstring(x)` is being deprecated in favour of `read(x, String)` for future googlers :)